# How can I link to a 'page' within a React SPA?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I've built a SPA in React and would like to link from another site to a specific 'page' on the SPA ie.
https://mywebsite.com/contact
But, as it's a SPA using 'React-Router' and 'Link' within 'Switch', an external linking-anchor to anything other than:
https://mywebsite.com or https://mywebsite.com/ naturally shows a 404 error. I expect this but wonder if there is a way to get to a specific part of my SPA without starting at the 'landing page'?
Would be great if someone knows a way and could point me in the right direction, if there is one, of course.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? The need you are describing is exactly what `react-router` and `link` are for, so it's possible there may be some kind of configuration issues happening.

Comment: This is an issue with your server only loading the React app when accessed though `./index`.   You need to configure it so that all pages go to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-helmet for each page

```
 import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
{....}
         <Helmet>
          <title>title</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
          <link rel="canonical" href={"***YOUR-URL/PATH***"} />
        </Helmet>
```

Also you should configure the server to always point to index for everything.

I hope this solves your problem, and if your app relies on so many pages you can use NextJS for Static Site Generation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, it doesn't really fix my needs. What I should have said is that I need to be able to send a link in an email (for example) to a page that isn't the landing page of the SPA but a 'page' that someone would click on the website to get to. ie. http://my-website.com is the site but I want to send a link to a friend for the forum page at http://my-website/forum

Comment: "Also you should configure the server to always point to index for everything." this should do. I applied it [in this website](https://www.acicadubai.com/information) and it works fine. Where did you host the website?